# URL Rewrite for joomla

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

I wanted change this joomla link

http://www.asbhtechsolutions.com/component/search/?searchphrase=all&searchword=simple%20program%20for%20java

to

http://www.asbhtechsolutions.com/search/simple-program-for-java

How can I do this?

Comment: dig some r&d with `JRoute` class, that help you to re-write your URL, and you have to change in Search Component don't forget to take back-up before any changes..

Comment: Can you please specify the path to these files?

Comment: now please check the answer and try to do it yourself.. if you stuck somewhere then come here with the `applying codes`, `error messages` and `what you want to achieve`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own router for the search component, the simplest way is to add a redirect to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I did not much knowledge about .htaccess rules. I try some rules which I get while searching but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your joomla version, but i checked in joomla 1.5.26,

`Just got to the joomla/components/com_search/controller.php`
and Search the function `search()`, at the bottom of this function you find the line that call the url with `JRoute` class.

`$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php'.$uri->toString(array('query', 'fragment')), false));`

now dig something your self to change according to your need, or read some documentation on [Joomla JRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/JRoute%3a%3a_/1.5), don't forget to change according to your Joomla Version.. Hope this help you..

Comment: Thanks. I am using joomla 3.0.x

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have enough experience with `.htaccess` try renaming `htaccess.txt` file to `.htaccess`. It's contained in your root directory of the Joomla installation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I've never seen a question about `.htaccess` like this before, it's not easy. I do not know if the code below would work. Just give a try to test this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /component/search/?searchphrase=all&searchword=%1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /component/search/?searchphrase=all&searchword=%1\%20%2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /component/search/?searchphrase=all&searchword=%1\%20%2\%20%3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /component/search/?searchphrase=all&searchword=%1\%20%2\%20%3\%20%4
```